# What happens if you save a call to super in a variable for future use?

Tags: python, super

Forgive me if I'm being ignorant of the obvious here, but what would happen if you save a call to super in a variable and use it later.

Here is a part of a class definition to show you what I mean.

```
class CaselessDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.super = super(CaselessDict, self) # save super
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = self.parsekey(key)
        return self.super.__getitem__(key) # use saved super
```

This came up when I was implementing this CaselessDict class and almost every method had super in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected thing happens: `self.super` will just hold a `super` object that acts just like `super(CaselessDict, self)`.

The problem with this approach is that each instance only has one `super` attribute, so if you had more classes that would use this technique, only the one that assigned to `super` last would function properly. Ouch! So, it's generally not a good idea to do this. You *could* name the attribute `__super` so it gets mangled, but I recommend just calling `super(CaselessDict, self)`, as everybody else does.

Of course, the grass is greener in Python 3, where a plain `super()` call is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The universe will blow up. No, nothing wrong should happen, even though it's not the usual usage. For the record, in Python 3, you can just use `super().foo(...)`, so it's basically useless to do there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a legitimate case where I *had* to do this kind of thing, involving classes that were dynamically loaded and reloaded. Here is a snippet that loads a module "a" containing class A, and creates and instance of it:

```
>>> import imp
>>> m = imp.find_module("a")
>>> a = imp.load_module("a", *m)
>>> a.A
<class 'a.A'>
>>> aobj = a.A()
>>> aobj.__class__
<class 'a.A'>
```

Now if I reimport "a", see what happens if I call isinstance with the previously created aobj:

```
>>> a = imp.load_module("a", *m)
>>> print a.A
<class 'a.A'>
>>> isinstance(aobj, a.A)
False
```

How this relates to super is that as of Python 2.6, `super(AClass,self)` added the check to make sure that the self reference was indeed an instance of AClass.  In my case, I used super in a method of "A", but once the "a" module was reimported and the "A" class redefined, my super references no longer worked! The a.A class had changed to something that my existing instances of a.A were no longer instances of, and so `super(a.A, self)` would begin to raise TypeErrors.  To resolve this, I did essentially what the OP did: in `__init__` I save a reference to super into an instance variable, which then gets used in other methods to upcall into base class methods.

Here is my full (and maybe a bit rambling) [blog post](http://thingspython.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/another-super-wrinkle-raising-typeerror/).